# redirect to / when *

Tags: nuxt.js, vue3

нужно сделать редирект в nuxt3, чтобы на любую неправильную ссылку переводил на '/'
есть такой код

```
routeRules: {
'*': {
  redirect: '/',
}
```

он находится в defineNuxtConfig, но сервер говорит "Сайт localhost выполнил переадресацию слишком много раз.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"